Question about the quotient group $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$
I know that $a\mathbb{Z} \cap b\mathbb{Z}=lcm(a,b)\mathbb{Z}$ and $a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}=mcd(a,b)\mathbb{Z}$. Is there something similar for $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$?

Did you mean $a\mathbb{Z} \cap b\mathbb{Z}=lcm(a,b)\color{red}{\mathbb Z}$ and $a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}=gcd(a,b)\color{red}{\mathbb Z}$ ?

@J.W.Tanner Yes, sorry. Edited.

$a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't make much sense unless $a \mid b$. In that case, we have $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/(b/a)\mathbb{Z}$.

What's mcd? Is it "Maximal common divisor"?

For $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ to be defined we need $b\mathbb{Z} \subseteq a\mathbb{Z}$, so we need to assume that $b=ak$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Then $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. The isomorphism $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ sends $x+b\mathbb{Z} \mapsto x/a + k\mathbb{Z}$, which makes sense because $x \in a\mathbb{Z}$. The inverse isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z} \to a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ sends $y + k\mathbb{Z} \mapsto ya + b\mathbb{Z}$.
A way of understanding this is that $\mathbb{Z} \cong a\mathbb{Z}$ as abelian groups, where the isomorphism is $x \mapsto ax$. The subgroup $k\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ gets mapped to the corresponding subgroup $b\mathbb{Z}$ of $a\mathbb{Z}$. So we have an "isomorphism of pairs" $(\mathbb{Z}, k\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{a}(a\mathbb{Z}, b\mathbb{Z})$. Such an isomorphism of pairs induces an isomorphism of quotients $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{a} a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$.
